# Cannot detach file-backed loop device after unmounting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, chroot, loopback

I have some image files that I often use for cross-compilation work via `chroot`. My usual deal is to create a loop device with it, mount its main partition, bind mount `/dev`, `/proc`, `/sys`, and maybe `/etc/resolv.conf` (I don't actually know what else is necessary for a proper `chroot`, but this seems to work fine), and `chroot` in to do work. All this seems to work, but then the loop device fails to actually detach via `losetup -d $LOOP_DEVICE` after unmounting everything. Instead, the `AUTOCLEAR` flag seems to get set, and that's about it. I tried to delete the underlying file (which succeeded), in an attempt to trick it into letting go, but all that did was add `(deleted)` to the end of the corresponding line in the output of `losetup -d $LOOP_DEVICE`. For a more concrete example, here's approximately what I did.

```bsh
# Pretend this never fails
LOOP_DEVICE=$(sudo losetup --partscan --file --show $SOME_IMAGE_FILE)

# Mount the desired partition for chrooting
sudo mount ${LOOP_DEVICE}${LOOP_PARTITION} $MOUNT_POINT

# Recursive bind mount and rslave, so it can be easily unmounted
for DIRECTORY in dev proc sys
do
    sudo mount --rbind /$DIRECTORY $MOUNT_POINT/$DIRECTORY
    sudo mount --make-rslave $MOUNT_POINT/$DIRECTORY
done

# Do what needs to be done in there
sudo chroot $MOUNT_POINT $SOME_COMMAND

# Clean up, unmount, and detach
sudo umount -R $MOUNT_POINT
sudo losetup -d $LOOP_DEVICE

# At this point, $LOOP_DEVICE still shows up, for some reason,
# even if $SOME_IMAGE_FILE is deleted
sudo losetup -l
```

I've also tried unmounting things individually, in case `umount -R` does not properly unmount everything, but that didn't resolve the issue. To reproduce this, perhaps try using a Raspberry Pi image or something, and running the above commands. Beware that it's just a rough list of commands to illustrate what I did, and is not really a script.

I've looked around for answers to this, but they're either old (e.g. one points to a kernel bug from a decade ago), unanswered, vague, or not as close to my case. I can't tell whether it's something wrong with what I'm doing that would cause the loop device to be undetachable, whether it really is a kernel bug that hasn't been fixed in a decade, or whether this question really is a duplicate of something I missed in my search. For context, I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 on kernel 5.4.0, but I think this happened to me on Ubuntu 20.04 on kernel 5.8.0, too.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Still happens on Debian Testing (Bookworm) with either their 5.18 kernel or a fresh 6.0RC1 kernel I compiled. Its all due to --make-rslave. It doesn't happen if I only mount dev or sys with --rbind BUT that causes a whole other issue of /dev and/or /sys then being unmounted from the normal OS after an unmount.

I don't know if this will ever be fixed. Per what I've found, its been around for a very long time.

This ONLY happens on a loopback device, nothing else. I can do the same thing on a USB drive without issue.

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer to the question